# Virtual Box wont let me run Win PE

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I created a custom Windows 7 install from this instruction set: http:// sybaspot.com/the-complete-guide-to-preparing-a-windows-7-deployment-image-using-audit-mode-and-sysprep-with-an-unattend-xml-answer-file/

I created a WINPE boot disk from thee Microsoft instructions found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523217%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I am using Virtual Box to create/capture the Windows install. I used the instructions found here: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox-1648868568 to boot from Windows PE to capture the installation.

In Virtual Box, I went to Settings > Storage and created a new hard disk and selected the file I created using the previous link. I made sure the drive containing Windows PE is on SATA 0. I boot the virtual drive and get Windows PE to load, but during the load screen I get the error of

"An error has occurred during virtual machine execution! The error details are shown below. You may try to correct the error and resume the virtual machine execution.

The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.

Error ID: BLKCACHE_IOERR
Severity: Non-Fatal Error"

I have over 30GB of space on the host drive. The USB drove has over 7GB of storage available. Why can't I boot into WinPE?

Comment: How much free space does the virtual HDD have?  If it has no free space that *might* explain the error.

Comment: There is 12GB of free space. I resolved the issue by just creating an ISO instead of a bootable UFD. Mounted the ISO using Virtual Clone Drive and ran it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to Settings: Storage then check - Use Host I/O cache?

I had a similar problem that when away when I used that setting.

Comment: _finally_ - this did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: or... perhaps not - it got rid of the error, but still not booting right...